# Execute Cucumber tests from the cmdline via an executable JAR without Maven

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

Here are the steps performed:

**Step 1:**
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149977/running-cucumber-tests-directly-from-executable-jar), I built a standalone jar with all dependencies included using `maven-shade-plugin`.

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</testSourceDirectory>
                <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</testClassesDirectory>
                <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-output/${timestamp}</reportsDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html -->
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <shadedClassifierName>standalone</shadedClassifierName>
                        <transformers>
                            <!-- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html -->
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>runners.RunCukesTest</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Added the `main()` method to the runner class and passed cmdline args based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696842/usage-java-cucumber-api-cli-main-options-filedirlineline), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128988/how-to-create-executable-jar-file-with-cucumber-tests), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51437433/how-to-run-mvn-cucumber-test-using-jar-file).

**RunCukesTest.java**

```
package runners;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.SnippetType;
import cucumber.api.cli.Main;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@CucumberOptions(features = { "src/main/resources/features" }, glue = { "steps" }, tags = { "not @ignore" }, plugin = {
        "pretty" }, monochrome = true)
public class RunCukesTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Begin running tests...");
        Main.main(new String[]{ "-g", "steps", "-t", "not @ignore", "-p", "pretty", "-m", "src/main/resources/features" });
    }

}
```

**Step 2:**
Tried to run executable JAR.

```
λ java -jar project-xyz-1.0.0-standalone.jar
Begin running tests...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: \path\to\jar\src\main\resources\features
        at cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterator$FileIterator.<init>(FileResourceIterator.java:63)
        at cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterator.<init>(FileResourceIterator.java:28)
        at cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterator.createFileResourceIterator(FileResourceIterator.java:14)
        at cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterable.iterator(FileResourceIterable.java:19)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader.loadFromFeaturePath(FeatureLoader.java:112)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader.load(FeatureLoader.java:48)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader.load(FeatureLoader.java:30)
        at cucumber.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.get(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:22)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:68)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:26)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:8)
        at runners.RunCukesTest.main(RunCukesTest.java:17)
```

It reads the `main()` method in the runner class but throws

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: \path\to\jar\src\main\resources\features

### UPDATE

It seems it is not reading the `features` directory inside the JAR.

```
Main.main(new String[]{ "-g", "steps", "-t", "not @ignore", "-p", "pretty", "-m", "src/main/resources/features" });
```

***How do I point to the `features` directory inside the JAR via the cmdline args?***

Comment: Use `classpath:features`

Comment: @mpkorstanje This worked! If you can post it as answer, I would be glad to upvote and accept as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed a relative path to Cucumber `src\main\resources\features`. Because you are executing the Jar this relative path is converted to an absolute path using the current working directory. However because `src\main\resources\features` is the source folder of your features, none could be found and you get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: \path\to\jar\src\main\resources\features

Instead you'll have to tell Cucumber that your features are on the class path. You do this by:

```
"classpath:features"
```

Comment: Thank you for that detailed explanation! And an honour to get an answer from the developer. Cheers!

Comment: No worries. Pay it forward.